# HMM : Learning states in a signal. (using hmmlearn python library)

Tags: time-series, hidden-markov-models, hmmlearn

I have time series data for which I am trying to learn 3 states in my HMM model. The output which I am getting is [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3307M.png) I want to get three separate states for the 3 distinct clusters of data points. But the first cluster has mixed states learned from HMM instead of a single state.

Here is my code for the same.

```
 model = hmm.GaussianHMM(n_components=3, covariance_type="full", verbose = True, n_iter =1000)
 model.fit(train_array1.reshape((-1,1)))
 Z1 = model.predict(test_array1_s.reshape(-1,1))  
 p = model.predict_proba(test_array1_s.reshape(-1,1))  
 plt.plot(p)
```

The plot of probabilites of each state for the test data is [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrBCB.png)

How can I get three distinct states for the the data?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How can I get three distinct states for the the data?

Comment: What are your input features? Have you checked that they are predictive of the state? Tried any feature engineering?

Comment: Is there an alternating pattern in your data? It is a bit hard to see from the plot. Can you plot it wider, so that the sequences of dataspoints are more clear?